# How to get all application link in a page?

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

url = 'http://www.brothersoft.com/windows/mp3_audio/midi_tools/'
html = urllib.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for a in soup.select('div.freeText dl a[href]'):
    print "http://www.borthersoft.com"+a['href'].encode('utf-8','replace')
```

What I get is:

```
http://www.borthersoft.com/synthfont-159403.html
http://www.borthersoft.com/midi-maker-23747.html
http://www.borthersoft.com/keyboard-music-22890.html
http://www.borthersoft.com/mp3-editor-for-free-227857.html
http://www.borthersoft.com/midipiano---midi-file-player-recorder-61384.html
http://www.borthersoft.com/notation-composer-32499.html
http://www.borthersoft.com/general-midi-keyboard-165831.html
http://www.borthersoft.com/digital-music-mentor-31262.html
http://www.borthersoft.com/unisyn-250033.html
http://www.borthersoft.com/midi-maestro-13002.html
http://www.borthersoft.com/music-editor-free-139151.html
http://www.borthersoft.com/midi-converter-studio-46419.html
http://www.borthersoft.com/virtual-piano-65133.html
http://www.borthersoft.com/yamaha-9000-drumkit-282701.html
http://www.borthersoft.com/virtual-midi-keyboard-260919.html
http://www.borthersoft.com/anvil-studio-6269.html
http://www.borthersoft.com/midicutter-258103.html
http://www.borthersoft.com/softick-audio-gateway-55913.html
http://www.borthersoft.com/ipmidi-161641.html
http://www.borthersoft.com/d.accord-keyboard-chord-dictionary-28598.html
```

There should be 526 application links to be printed out.
But I only get twenty?
What is not enough with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only 20 application links in a page.

You have to iterate all pages to get all links:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

for page in range(1, 27+1): # currently there are 27 pages.
    url = 'http://www.brothersoft.com/windows/mp3_audio/midi_tools/{}.html'.format(page)
    html = urllib.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    for a in soup.select('div.freeText dl a[href]'):
        print "http://www.borthersoft.com"+a['href'].encode('utf-8','replace')
```

Comment: What about if the application page increase automatically?

Comment: @wanmohdpayed, I don't understand your comment question.. May you don't want hard-code page count (`27`)?  Then, parse page number yourself. If there are more pages continue to next page, or break.

Comment: I mean what if brothersoft add the number of page. We wouldn't know it if we did not check it everytime right?

Comment: @wanmohdpayed, It depends on how *brothersoft* add new link to the page. In worst case, you should check every page.

Comment: Can make a loop such as counter + 1 for this?

Comment: @wanmohdpayed, I'm sorry. I don't understand again. It would be better to post another question so other people could help.

Comment: I mean, can use other way or not besides using this solution?